# undefined method `gsub'...(NoMethodError) for docusign

Tags: ruby-1.9.3, gsub, nomethoderror, soap4r, docusignapi

After installing the docusign gem and dependent soap4r gem via github (git://github.com/felipec/soap4r.git), I get this issue when trying to run the server

```
user$ rails s
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bundler/gems/soap4r-5372d16ab9a9/lib/xsd/charset.rb:13: warning: variable $KCODE is no longer effective
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bundler/gems/soap4r-5372d16ab9a9/lib/soap/property.rb:68: warning: encoding option is ignored - u
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bundler/gems/soap4r-5372d16ab9a9/lib/soap/property.rb:69: warning: encoding option is ignored - u
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bundler/gems/soap4r-5372d16ab9a9/lib/soap/property.rb:70: warning: encoding option is ignored - u
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/docusign-0.8.0/lib/docusign/request_recipient_token_client_urls.rb:5:in `block in <class:RequestRecipientTokenClientURLs>': undefined method `gsub' for :onSigningComplete:Symbol (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/docusign-0.8.0/lib/docusign/request_recipient_token_client_urls.rb:5:in `map'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/docusign-0.8.0/lib/docusign/request_recipient_token_client_urls.rb:5:in `<class:RequestRecipientTokenClientURLs>'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/docusign-0.8.0/lib/docusign/request_recipient_token_client_urls.rb:2:in `<module:Docusign>'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/docusign-0.8.0/lib/docusign/request_recipient_token_client_urls.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/docusign-0.8.0/lib/docusign.rb:36:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler.rb:119:in `require'
    from /Users/user/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/reaslo/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>
```

I investigated

> request_recipient_token_client_urls.rb

but only found

> CALLBACKS = instance_methods.select { |m| m =~ /^on/ }.reject { |m| m =~ /=/ }.map { |m| m.gsub(/^on/, '').underscore }

I don't understand what is going wrong here. I can only suspect that there is an issue with soap4r because I had to install it via a github version that is compatible with ruby 1.9

Answer (score 0):

That code snippet is incorrect; it's trying to call `gsub` on one of the method names returned by `instance_methods`, which are symbols, not strings.  I'm guessing the top-of-tree in git is not stable here.